# Secret Santa matching in Java - What can it be abstracted to, so I can solve it?

Tags: java, graph, variable-assignment, jgrapht

I have got a Secret Santa assignment project going on. The situation is the following:

> We're organizing a university Secret Santa gift exchange. There are 4000 students in the faculty participating.
>
> In their participation, they had the ability to choose one of the following giftee picking options:
>
> 1. I want to gift to any other student, no matter his faculty
> 2. I want my giftee to be of any other faculty but only if that faculty is under the Science Faculty (Since we're in the computer science department ourselves)
> 3. I want my giftee to be of my own faculty only.

Now, I've been thinking of a way to **abstract** this problem to something else, so I can solve it. I've got the list of imaginary participants, and the problem smelled like Graph theory, so I organized it into a **Graph** (with [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/)).

Now, every participant is a node in my graph.

The problems are:

- I was thinking of putting Edges from every participant to another if the gifting operation is valid (e.g. someone that wants to gift to any faculty will have connections to all other 3999 participants), but that operation is expensive and slow as heck. I'll end up with **around a million edges**, 1.6m if every participant decides to be generous. Is this something I just have to accept? I don't even think my computer has enough RAM to store all that during implementation! **EDIT**: *I was being stupid. My graph is omnidirectional and I wasn't checking for already existing edges when creating new, as edge(vertex0, vertex3) would be the same as edge(vertex3, vertex0). With a simple if-check, my graph is now built and very manageable. Please disregard this.*
- If I take the hit and end up building the edged Graph (**EDIT**: Which I did), what problem can I abstract it to, so I can pick an algorithm and solve it? Is this a *Stable Marriage* problem? An *assignment* problem?

Any help would be appreciated.
Have a good holiday.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for Programmers, since it's a bit general, but I'll note that the last option is pretty restrictive, and you could probably start by eliminating a lot of potential matches that way.

Comment: would it be hypothetically possible for a student to give away 3000 gifts to 3000 different persons?? if so, give them an option setting the amount of gifts they are willing to send out. this will reduce the complexity greatly

Comment: @BartHofma Every student will get matched to a single giftee, and will send out one gift.

Comment: then why connect them to 3000 others, and not just 1 random person from the right category?

Comment: @BartHofma Because I was thinking the Edge as Giftability, not the final choice of edge1-gifting-to-edge2. I wanted to run an algorithm on the structure that will ensure everyone who CAN get a match, will. **For example**, if I start randomly choosing the first valid edge as "ok, vertexYou will gift to vertexHim", we may end up assigning many willing-to-gift-anywhere matches with same-faculty members, and other-faculty members not getting assigned to any gifters because, earlier in our solution, we ran out of universal gifters, wasting them on same-faculty giftees. Can that haappen?

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis that explanation made thing a lot clearer, i'll have to think about it. It's showing similarities to the bankers-algorithm though.... is the graph a necessity? or just a tool you think is needed to solve the problem?

Comment: @BartHofma Just a hunch I had that the abstraction of the problem would be solveable in Graph structure. It is not by any means a necessity and I'd be eager to hear your thoughts on a different approach, sir.

Comment: maybe i'm thinking too simple. Wouldn't you just put the people in 3 different lists after signup closed. Then deal with them in the reverse order as appears in your question (saving your 'wildcards') for last?